# Docker. MySQL image. Can't change my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, docker-compose

I have such a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    database:
        container_name: test_db
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - ./docker/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
          - test_db_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    test_db_data:
```

and I want to edit the `sql_mode`.

`./docker/my.cnf` contains:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=""
```

But when I connect to db from my local machine and run `SELECT @@sql_mode;` I receive:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sudo into my.cnf

Comment: @AlirezaAmrollahi I don't understand you. What do you mean?

Comment: You are overriding the default my.cnf file when you mount the volume on top of it https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/86431f073b3d2f963d21e33cb8943f0bdcdf143d/8.0/config/my.cnf . Try adding to the default file.

Comment: @yamenk It's not the problem, cause in that case sql_mode would be as I want. I've checked mounted file and I see, that it was not mounted. Working on the solution. Would be glad to hear your suggestion)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have changed

```
- ./docker/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
```

to

```
- ./docker/my.cnf:/etc/alternatives/my.cnf
```

As a side-bonus looks like it's considered to be a "better practice".

Comment: Rather than answering your own question and asking a new one in answer, I would suggest editing/updating your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't think so. The original issue was **Can't change my.cnf file**. I have solved it and posted an answer. I don't understand the root of the bug, but I have solved it. If sb can explain it — ok. No — I'm ok with that and don't need a new SO question for that.

Comment: Please show what the finished docker-compose file looks like?  Did you remove the second volumes command?

Comment: @slashdottir sorry, but I don't have it anymore :(

Answer (score 35):

You can add this to your db service:

```
command: --sql_mode=""
```

so its:

```
    database:
    container_name: test_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
        - ./docker/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf
    environment:
        - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
        - "MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db"
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - test_db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    command: --sql_mode=""
```

Comment: Interesting idea. Thanks.

Comment: @D.R. it worked in my situation, not sure if it will in yours.

Comment: For me this was the only approach that worked. Thanks heaps Brad.

Comment: This is a great solution, clean

Comment: This worked for me, i agree command: --sql_mode="" and works.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use only one "volumes" directive. Maybe it uses only the last one.

Comment: OMG. I have not noticed. I've solved the issue, but the second time it was in one `volume` "command" (don't know how to name it).