# Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode in mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a big problem when I want to make a view.

```sql
CREATE VIEW AnneeBillet (ANNEE_BILLETS, CHIFFRES)
AS SELECT YEAR(FIN_RESERVATION), sum(TYPE.PRIX*NOMBRE)
FROM TYPE, BILLET
where TYPE.TYPE = BILLET.TYPE;
```

I have this error :

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list
> contains nonaggregated column 'parc.BILLET.FIN_RESERVATION'; this is
> incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I have already tried many solutions like putting

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

But I'm with a docker container and I've seen that I had to modify directly the configuration file to have what I want.

Then, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374644/docker-mysql-image-cant-change-my-cnf-file) on stackoverflow but I can't do

```
--sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))
```

in my docker-compose because I have an error like this :

> mysql_1  |      2021-04-27T07:59:53.283400Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077]
> [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value '(SELECT
> REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''))' to 'sql_mode'.

Please help me, I'm fed up with this problem.

Comment: Either remove YEAR(FIN_RESERVATION) from the output or add GROUP BY by this expression (depends on the logic).

Comment: Rather than hacking MySQL, you should fix your aggregation query to do the right thing (e.g. by adding `group by year(...)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `GROUP BY YEAR(FIN_RESERVATION)` to the end of your query or change it to `MIN(YEAR(FIN_RESERVATION))` - you can also use max. If you didn't do these things and instead changed the mode MySQL would simply arbitrarily pick one of the year values anyway

Only full group by is a good thing

Comment: This is the real answer. I had the same issue when the values I selected were different numbers grouped by another column. MySQL didn't know which number to choose so it produced the error. Once I added MIN() or MAX() it worked great. Thank you.

Comment: I thought order by would take care of this. Is there any way to just tell group by to use the first row?

Comment: "Only full group by is a good thing" why? What's the real reason? I use partial group by without any drawback because I tested the query and I need to do it with partial group by. There are plenty of features misused by devs, so they should be forced to prevent the devs errors?

Answer (score 2):

If you permanently want to disable `only_full_group_by` on startup, you can add:

```
sql-mode= "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

To your `my.ini` or `my.cnf` under `'[mysqld]'`.

Also if you get the error:

> "Error while setting value 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,​NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,​NO_ZERO_DATE,​ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,​NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'"

as I did, you can get around this issue, by first clearing all sql-modes by putting `sql-mode=""` above:

```
sql-mode= "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an sql expression as the value of --sql_mode.  Run `SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','')); SELECT @@sql_mode;` in your server and use the value it shows with --sql_mode.